# How to fill a hollow object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, fill

I'm working with a **complex** shape, but for the sake of getting a solution, let's say I draw a circle with the circle tool, and then I do a smaller circle inside of it. I select both objects and use pathfinder to erase the smaller circle on the top. Now you should get a "donut" shape.

How can I fill the inside of the donut? Is there any tool to create a selectable shape out of a hollow shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

You have what is called a compound path.

You can **Right Click → Release Compound Path** and then fill each individual shape.

This works better on simple shapes, as it can have some unwanted side effects. For more complex shapes, see the next solution.

---

#### Option 2

You can use the *Shape Builder Tool* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) and then just select your path and click in the empty area you want to convert to a shape.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click will *add* a path
<kbd>Alt</kbd> click will *remove* a path

Comment: Thank you, Option 1 did the job. However, I need to see tutorials to learn about Shape Builder Tool as I'm not understanding straight how or where to use it. Thank you!

Comment: @Germán maybe [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ni3W.gif) will help explain that process, notice that the one hexagon is missing, it is currently not filled with any path. I just selected all the shapes and clicked in the hollow area I wanted to *build* into a shape.